# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}U_n = \sin(U_{n-1}) + \cos(U_{n-2})$ using pencil and paper.

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Define a sequence $U_n = \sin(U_{n-1}) + \cos(U_{n-2})$
where $U_0 = 0$, $U_1 = 0  $
How do you find the value of $U=\lim_{n\to\infty} U_n$?

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: It doesn't come from anywhere, I just made it up in my head.

Comment: Hint: if there is a $U=\lim_{n\to\infty}U_n$, then you must have $U=\sin(U)+\cos(U)$; can you see why? The trick will be proving convergence.

Comment: hmmmm but how do you solve it?

Comment: You can only solve it numerically.

Comment: (Incidentally, I added TeX to your question; it is the standard for questions on this site, and if you want to ask questions here you ought to learn how to use it.)

Comment: I know the answer(using my calculator), but I want to know how to solve it with my hands.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I think I should learn it...

Comment: [How to use MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/29979#29979).

Comment: There's no reason to think that any given equation can be solved by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I edit this answer because I missed the "using pencil and paper".*

As @Steven Stadnicki commented, if there is convergence, the limit is given by the zero of function
$$f(U)=U-\sin(U)-\cos(U)$$ The solution requires a numerical method (as @Toby Mak commented).

We can have a decent approximation of the solution. Graphing the function, we can notice that the solution is  $$\frac \pi 3 < x < \frac \pi 2$$

Around $\frac \pi 2$, we can build a Taylor series. This would give
$$f(U)=\frac{\pi -2}{2} +2\left(U-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)-\cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)}{n!} \left(U-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^n $$ which would give, after series reversion
$$U=\frac{\pi }{2}+t-\frac{t^2}{4}+\frac{5 t^3}{24}-\frac{31 t^4}{192}+\frac{287
   t^5}{1920}-\frac{3313 t^6}{23040}+O\left(t^7\right)$$ with $t=\frac{1}{2} \left(f(U)-\frac{\pi }{2}+1\right)$. Making $f(U)=0$, then $t=\frac{2-\pi }{4}\approx -\frac 27$ (using $\pi \sim \frac{22}{7}$)  will give more end more accurate results

We could also compute the first iterate of the original Halley (with $x_0=\frac \pi 2$).
Then, the approximate solution is given by
$$U\sim \frac{16+10 \pi -\pi ^2}{36-2 \pi }\approx 1.26347$$ while the exact solution is $1.25873$.

Doing the same with the original Householder method would give
$$U\sim \frac{-216-116 \pi +14 \pi ^2+\pi ^3}{-472+40 \pi +2 \pi ^2}\approx 1.25918$$ which is much better.